# Preference in parameters order for argc, argv

Tags: c, function, arguments

Trivial question.

I have functions which manipulate the command line string, and I found easier to pass argc and argv to them, so that I delegate the treatment and I don't invent extra things before calling this functions.

```
myFunction(argc, argv, with, extra, things);
```

- `argc` is a number (type `int`)
- `argv` is a pointer to strings (type `char*[]`)

But usually, functions that get a pointer and a size reclaim the pointer first and the size next.

Should I write all my functions like `(argc, argv)` or should I mimic the more usual `(pointer, size)` meaning `(argv, argc)` ?

Comment: My opinion: keep `argc` and `argv` in their (inverted) usual order; write other `array/len` pairs in natural order. BTW voted to close as opinion-based. So ... `foobar(argc, argv, arr, len)` Don't ever change the **name** and/or **meaning** of `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: @pmg It's not a matter of opinion. We have standards for a reason, people just need to fall in line with what's required by the language.

Comment: @Lundin I think you’re misunderstanding the question. It’s not about `main` (or other entry points), it’s about functions called *by the user* to which these arguments are dispatched.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In that case, we found the answer to the question "should I name my function parameters argc argv like in main just for the heck of it".

Comment: @Lundin Hmm well presumably these parameters receive the `argc` and `argv` arguments when being called. It’s a fairly widespread convention to preserve this naming for user functions in this scenario. What else would you call them? `args`/`args_len`? Sure, I guess you could.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Those names are appropriate for a function used to parse the command line arguments, but only then.

Comment: @Lundin … or when (directly or indirectly) calling `execv*`. Or probably some similar scenarios. — Under what other circumstances are you passing `argv` on to another function, anyway? Because those would probably also appropriate circumstances, then. At least I don’t see why they wouldn’t be.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring various subjective opinions on the matter.

There is one reason to put the size before the data in modern C, and that is because using VLA-type parameters using the passed size gives self-documenting code and possibilities of increased static analysis/compiler warnings

Examples:

`void func (size_t size, int array[size]);`

`void parse_cmdline (int argc, char* argv[argc]);`

In order to utilize this feature of (pointer-to) VLA, the size parameter must be declared to the left of the data parameter.

If you don't take advantage of this feature, then the order doesn't matter.